# Strict mode in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript and came across the term "strict mode". I know that it is used to indicate to the compiler that the code should be examined stricter. Then I went on testing this: first I tried this:

```html
function test() {
    "use strict";
    a = 4;
    alert(a);
}
```

I didn't get an alert and thought that it is quite logical as an error is thrown because "a" is not defined. Then I tried this:

```html
{
    "use strict";
    a = 4;
    alert(a);
}
```

After refreshing the page an alert was shown saying "4". So my question is when is the strict mode "working" and when it isn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the [MDN page on strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

> Strict mode applies to entire scripts or to individual functions. It doesn't apply to block statements enclosed in `{}` braces; attempting to apply it to such contexts does nothing.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I'll take a note.